# FBX Converter has no texture/animation when imported to Blender?

Tags: export, blender-internal-render-engine, import

When attempting to import my FBX files to Blender, I received an error saying version 6100 not supported, use 7100 instead. At the suggestion of a forum thread I found, I am now using the official FBX Converter from Autodesk to convert these models.

When viewed in the FBX Converter application, the animations work as expected (no textures though). When I export as a Binary and import to Blender, the animations are no longer there. I have also tried as ASCII but Blender apparently cannot import that.

Can anyone shed some light on how to resolve this?